# Recover data from lost partiton after install ubuntu

Tags: recovery, data-recovery

i have a 500GB HDD. when i install Ubuntu i was made a mistake that i install Ubuntu by replacing windows 7. after installation Ubuntu run fine. But my HDD have only one part ion of whole 500Gb. Now how can i get my previous data from this HDD?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally i restore all partitions without losing data except Windows system files. :)

Comment: Hey I have same problem, In Ubuntu I was trying to make a pendrive of 8gb as bootable to install windows 7, By mistake I made external HDD of 1tb as bootable. Now I can see only bootable related files in HDD. I can't see my original data which is of 500gb in HDD.. can you please help me how to recover all files in my HDD???

Answer (score 1):

Make a live bootable GNU/Linux system and run on your pc. Install "TestDisk" Package. Then Restore old partition table with test disk. For more info visit this link. [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_with_testdisk)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I installed Ubuntu on a 50 GB of unallocated space on a laptop already containing Windows 8.1. I lost all my partition and a single partition was created by Ubuntu.

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) is a great tool to help you work with the lost data and partitions. Believe me testdisk is really a great tool to help you recover your data.

For a complete walkthrough on the process to recover your all partitions and the data you can visit this page [TestDisk - Step by Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)